# How to redirect 404 error to specific url?

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, 404, 404-page, cms-pages

I've faced the problem: my seo-specialist asked me to redirect all 404 to same url (**/404.html**). Not to show content on noRoute page but redirect to this url.

I've made changes in **/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php**:

```
/**
 * Render CMS 404 Not found page
 *
 * @param string $coreRoute
 */
public function noRouteAction($coreRoute = null)
{
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');

    $pageId = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Cms_Helper_Page::XML_PATH_NO_ROUTE_PAGE);
    if (!Mage::helper('cms/page')->renderPage($this, $pageId)) {
        $this->_forward('defaultNoRoute');
    }
    $this->_redirect($pageId);
}
```

It works on local version but doesn't on live.

When I comment headers it works:

```
// $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
// $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');
```

But I think it's incorrect solution, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather then changing core module I would suggest you to look into

`System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages > Default No-route URL`

Here you can see that default no-route URL is `cms/index/noRoute`. So just change this from your module controller and do your changes. For example `(YOUR_ROUTE/CONTROLLER NAME/ACTION NAME)`

Comment: I've moved file to **/app/code/local/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php** but it doesn't seem to be overriden. I mean I can't override this file in usual way